# aws codedeploy error The old deployment was still in status 'Active' after the deployment timeout. The configured timeout is 10 minutes

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

while running code deploy getting error as The old deployment was still in status 'Active' after the deployment timeout. The configured timeout for this action is 10 minutes.

it showing deployment in running stage after configured timeout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAFTI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qhs.png)

Comment: Exactly same issue here

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Task log.

In the Task Tab, click 'stopped' and see logs.
Most common reasons are about Authority. Check the ECS IAM Role has enough permissions to access resources.

(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html)